# How to send deep form data as array or object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am putting all passengers info together like this with input names:

```
passenger[1][name]
passenger[1][surname]
passenger[1][idnumber]
passenger[2][name]
passenger[2][surname]
passenger[2][idnumber]
```

When I post like this, they are not getting as object or array like how we do in php.So, I don't know how can I do this, because I need all those informations.

I tried to make a data names like `passenger_1_name` but there is another problem getting appear.

How can I use variable name in key name ?

Like `passenger_COUNTERVARIABLE_name` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
let passengerName = 'john', passengerSurname = 'doe';
let passengers = [];
passengers.push({name: passengerName, surname: passengerSurname})
```

Gives out

```
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "surname": "doe"
  }
]
```

Comment: but this data is coming from to inputs by user. so how should i name inputs ?

Comment: Yes this data is entered manually, if you need it to be a variable, replace the 'john' etc with corresponding variable names.
What do you mean by `how should i name inputs`

Answer (score 0):

It might not be possible to get multidimensional array as we get in PHP, But below input names will provide you the work around for your problem.

```
passenger_name[]
passenger_surname[]
passenger_idnumber[]
```

You don't need to assign keys in your input names, browser will handle this.

On server side you will get three different array for each information with same keys, you can loop over single array and get other corresponding values based on keys.

```
var passenger = [];
for(i=1;i<=form.passenger_name.length;i++){
    passenger['name'][] = form.passenger_name[i];
    passenger['surname'][] = form.passenger_surname[i];
    passenger['idnumber'][] = form.passenger_idnumber[i];
} 

console.log(passenger);
```